# Atmosphere Framework - "Websocket reconnect maximum try reached" after some minutes of idle time

Tags: websocket, atmosphere

I am using Atmosphere Framework in my project. For client side i am using atmosphere.js

If browser and server are staying idle for some minutes, connection will be closed with the message: "Websocket reconnect maximum try reached".

How can we avoid this error? Is there any way to reconnect to the server if this error has come?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this probelm?